# I have created a layout and partial folder in views. I didn't understand why this code is used in app.js

Tags: node.js, express, mern

```
app.engine('hbs',hbs({extname:'hbs',defaultLayout:'layout',layoutsDir:__dirname+'/views/layout/',partialsDir:__dirname+'/views/partials/'}))
```

Why is hbs, extname, defaultLayout used here?

Answer (score 0):

app.engine(ext,callback) will takes two arguments, one is the extension and the other is a callback function. Therefore, hbs is the extension you are using to create your views.

you can also take a look at handelbars's github repository when they mentioned extname from [here](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#extnamehandlebars).

https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#extnamehandlebars

This link also might be helpful for you, they mentioned the defaultLayout option and what it means.

This [link](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#layouts) might help you understand why to use defaultLayout.

> A layout is simply a Handlebars template with a {{{body}}} placeholder.
> Usually it will be an HTML page wrapper into which views will be
> rendered.

https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#layouts